# Image is stretched when inset

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I have a UIImageView and I'm trying to inset the image. The problem is that when I try to inset it the image becomes stretched inside the image view, to the point where you can't see it. You can only see it if you make the image a 3x inside image assets. But when I remove the inset, the image stretches to the bounds of the image view. How can I fix this. Here is the code.

```
var myImage = UIImage(named: "black-phone-auricular-2")!
    let myInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 15, 15, 15)
    myImage = myImage.resizableImage(withCapInsets: myInsets, resizingMode: .stretch)
    imageview.image = myImage
```

Comment: Can you show your actual image?

Comment: Don't inset the image. Inset the image view. — You are not actually insetting anything, by the way. A resizable image is not an inset image. Don't use a resizable image unless you know what it is for. (Hint: it is for stretching. )

Answer (score 0):

add this line of code and it will not be stretched:

```
              imageview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```